# How to get the HTML ID of a particular radio button in a RadioButtonList

Tags: jquery, webforms

I'm try to use jQuery to check whether or not a particular element in a RadioButtonList is selected. In the past I've used Control.ClientID to get the HTML ID of the element, but this just gives the ID of the whole list. I'd like to get the ID of a particular element in the list so I can see if it is checked or not.

Basically I have:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="AttendedStudySessions" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="False">No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Which generates:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="True" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$AttendedStudySessions" id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_MainContent_AttendedStudySessions_0"><label for="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_MainContent_AttendedStudySessions_0">Yes</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="False" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$AttendedStudySessions" id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_MainContent_AttendedStudySessions_1"><label for="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_MainContent_AttendedStudySessions_1">No</label></td>
</tr>
```

And I want to be able to check whether one of those has been selected using something similar to this:

```
jQuery('#<%= AttendedStudySessions.Items.GetByValue("False").UniqueID %>').prop('checked');
```

But obviously, that doesn't work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

var id = $("input[@name=radioGroup]:checked").attr('id');

?

Comment: Yeah, duh, what was I thinking, forgot about the ":checked" selector Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if($("input[name*=AttendedStudySessions]:checked").length > 0){
  //The radio button is checked
}
```

Comment: +1 for the Name* selector. I've never used that before, but just looked up the jQuery documentation on it and that is certainly an interesting solution.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the checked value, or null if none is checked:

```
$('input[type="radio"][name*="<%= AttendedStudySessions.UniqueID %>"][checked="checked"]').val()
```